# interpolation with neural networks

Tags: python, neural-network, interpolation

Let's suppose you have this dataset :

```
       1.05   1.10   1.15   1.20   1.25  
0.2   0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  
0.3   0.350  0.350  0.350  0.350  0.350  
0.4   0.615  0.619  0.623  0.626  0.628  
0.5   0.805  0.816  0.826  0.834  0.839
```

is there any way to interpolate for example 0.389 and 1.168 using neural networks instead of just using a simple interpolation or bilinear interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`tf.keras.Sequential`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential):

```
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Set all random seeds for reproducibility on the same machine at least
RANDOM_SEED = 1
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(RANDOM_SEED)
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(RANDOM_SEED)

# Data
x1 = np.array([1.05, 1.10, 1.15, 1.20, 1.25])
x2 = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
y = np.array([[0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
              [0.350, 0.350, 0.350, 0.350, 0.350],
              [0.615, 0.619, 0.623, 0.626, 0.628],
              [0.805, 0.816, 0.826, 0.834, 0.839]])
X1_mesh, X2_mesh = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
X = np.column_stack((X1_mesh.ravel(), X2_mesh.ravel()))
Y = y.ravel()

# Model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)

# Predict
new_point = np.array([[1.168, 0.389]])
predicted_value = model.predict(new_point)
print(predicted_value)
```

**Example Output:**

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 55ms/step
[[0.5972232]]
```

Comment: I have a question , what if you want to just interpolate 0.2 and 1.168? I just tested it in google colab and the result is negative, why is that?

Comment: At boundaries, the model might perform worse.

Comment: Yeah you are right since zero pops up but what if you interpolate 0.3?

Comment: Every example with 0.2 is 0.000?

Comment: You are right, I did not notice that part, thanks for much for the answer , by the way , I am having issues with tensorflow I mean to install it , could you please help me? I have tried several times but I did not sucess .

Comment: Use colab? Do you have pytorch installed?

Comment: I was using colab and pycharm but it did not work , I don't know why, thanks so much for the code , I was sure that it was possible to get the values without interpolating since I made a program before

Comment: I have a question now, what if I want to use for x1  shape of 20 and x2 shape of 119 , the y shape of (119,20) , can the code be modifed ? I ask about this since when I tested with [1.1789, 0.489] the value of output changes at the beggining was 0.81045085 with shape of (4,5) but now with a shape of (119,20) is [0.80769724], why is that?